# How to implement Breadth-first search traversal?

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

I can't clearly understand how to implement breadth first search using a queue.

this is what i've understood:

```
 create queue Q
 enqueue root onto Q

while( !Q.empty() )
{
  node t = Q.deque();
  if(t is the goal we're seeking)
      return t;
  enqueue   t->leftchild
  enqueue   t->rightchild
}
```

so what am i missing out here?

Comment: Looks right.  What's the problem?  (It will, of course, only work for binary trees as it stands.)

Comment: Assuming you are searching a binary tree, you haven't missed anything... In the more general case of an arbitrary graph, you would also need to keep track of which nodes you have already visited, and enqueue all unvisited neighbours.

Comment: in the case of an 8-puzzle, or even a game of chess, every state could lead to much more than 2 states - so will i be following the same approach even then, or will it be more convenient to limit the no. of children for each node to a manageable amount?

Comment: Assuming you are traversing a binary tree - you are missing the base caluse: `if (t->leftchild != null) enqueue t->leftchild`, unless your queue implementation silently ignore nulls inserted to it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you wrongly assume that each state has exactly 2 states that can be generated from it.

The right algorithm is:

```
BFS(G,v):
      create a queue Q
      enqueue v onto Q
      mark v
      while Q is not empty:
          t ← Q.dequeue()
          if t is what we are looking for:
              return t
          for all edges (t,u) in G do
             if u is not marked:
                  mark u
                  enqueue u onto Q
```

Credit for [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

Comment: He is clearly talking about BFS for binary trees, so I don't see how this is helpful

Comment: In order not to visit a node more than one time, you mark him. When you expand node, you push to the stack only the nodes that you have not marked yet. (have not seen yet)